# столкнулся с проблемой subprocess has no attribute 'sheck_output'

Tags: python, subprocess

'''`import subprocess, re, sys`

'''`command = "netsh wlan show profile"`

'''`networks = subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True)`

'''`networks_names_list = re.findall("(?:.*\s*:\s)(.*)", networks)`

'''`result = ""`

'''`for networks_name in networks_names_list:`

'''    `command = "netsh wlan show profile " + networks_name + " key=clear"`

'''    `current_result = subprocess.sheck_output(command, shell=True)`

'''    `result = current_result`

'''`print(result)`

Comment: Что такое `sheck_output`? Откуда вы это взяли?

Comment: `sheck_output` --> `check_output`

Comment: я слепой до бесконечности правильно будет сheck_output

Answer (score 1):

Надо заменить `subprocess.sheck_output(command, shell=True)` на `subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True)`.